# Create Pandas column with the max of two calculated values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I want to create a column with the maximum value between 2 values calculated from other columns of the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [-2, 8, 1]})

df['Max Col'] = max(df['A']*3, df['B']+df['A'])


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The desired outcome is a new df column ['Max Col'] with the maximum value of the above calculations.

I know there is the long solution of creating two new columns with the calculations and then apply *.max(axis=1)*. I am looking for a straight solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `np.maximum`:

```
df['max'] =np.maximum(df['A']*3, df['B']+df['A'])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  max
0  1 -2    3
1  2  8   10
2  3  1    9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [-2, 8, 1]})
# map the max function to a zip of your calculations
df['max'] = list(map(max, zip(df['A']*3, df['B']+df['A'])))
print(df)

   A  B  max
0  1 -2    3
1  2  8   10
2  3  1    9
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `apply` method -

```
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(x['A']*3, x['A'] + x['B']), axis=1)
```